# How can I detect what application is running on OSX

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, background-process

I want to make my application as menu bar app and I made it already.
And also I want to track what application is running.

NSRunningApplication method returns all runnng applications.
But I want to detect the only application that is activated now. (with mouse click or command + tab...)
How can I find that?

I made code below :

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(performTimerBasedUpdate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)performTimerBasedUpdate {
     nowRunning = [NSRunningApplication currentApplication];
     nowRunningName = [nowRunning localizedName];
}
```

But, It returns the application name that I made (self).

- Answered

I finally find the answer : thank you i-blis.
I can get the activated application with filter.
I didn't know about isActive property!

```
runningApplications_ = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];
nowRunning = [[runningApplications_ filteredArrayUsingPredicate:isActive] objectAtIndex:0];
bundleIdentifier_ = [nowRunning bundleIdentifier];
localizedName = [nowRunning localizedName];
```

Comment: you mean the application the user is using?

Comment: "NSRunningApplication method returns all runnng application. But I want to detect application that is running." - Color me confused.

Comment: I updated my question. The currentApplication method always returns the application I made. I want to get the application that is activated. ps. Sorry for my humble English skill :)

Comment: thank you for the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily find if an application is active with `isActive`. Then peek the `localizedName` or `bundleIdentifier` at your will. I am not really fluent in Objective-C but with Macruby syntax you'll get it in the following way :

```
NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace.runningApplications
    .select { |e| e.isActive == true }
    .map { |e| e.localizedName }
```

You may need to filter out your own application: I did not test how menu bar apps are handled in this regard.

Comment: You're welcome (and sorry for the Macruby rather than Obj-C idiom).

Answer (score 2):

```
NSWorkspace *workSpace = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];

NSString *appPathIs = [workSpace fullPathForApplication:appName];

NSString *identifier = 
   [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:appPathIs] bundleIdentifier];

NSArray *selectedApps = 
   [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:identifier];
```

Comment: Thank you, AlbrahimZ. But the answer that I want to get is How can I find appName :)

Comment: Well get the name from the Array, loop through it to find the name( in the code i posted..)